# How to Hide ImageView if there is No Image Url?

Tags: android

Greetings of the Day !!. I have a drop-down list where user selects multiple menus. Based on Selection, Data is populating. My problem is if user Selected a picture for One from down item  and change menu item from Drop Down but image is displaying same for every Drop Down Menu. How to display image for only if that drop down Image contains Image Url ??

```
if (!ActivityFromServer.get(i).getImageurl().equals("N.A")) {
                    try {

                        imageLoader.displayImage(ActivityFromServer.get(i)
                                .getImageurl(),
                                imageviewActivityAttachmentFile,
                                optionsItems);
                        activityindex = i;
                        checkMarkAttachement(booleanActivity,
                                imageviewActivitychecked,
                                metrics.widthPixels);
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                } else {
                    try {
                        imageview_Attachementfile.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                }

                ShowAlerForExistData();
                return;
            }
```

Comment: if images are not there than what you are getting in getImageurl?

Comment: What is the exact condition when the image url is not present?  It looks like you are checking if the string is not equal to "N.A" which seems strange to me.  Figure out the exact condition and let us know.

Comment: Not getting your Question please elaborate more.